# File upload in Jenkins using File Parameter

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, automated-tests, selenide

I have a test in which .csv file is uploaded to the application.

```
    public void userUploadFile() {
    LocalFileDetector detector = new LocalFileDetector();
    File localFile = detector.getLocalFile("src/test/resources/rcicsod_02.csv");
    $(chooseFileBttn).sendKeys(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
    $x(uploadBttn).click();
```

Set up build in Jenkins, added File Parameter in Jenkins, put the location as

src/test/resources/rcicsod_02.csv

where rcicsod_02.csv is my file name. In my code, I have provided the same path to be read from.
Here Jenkins returns error:

```
Caused by: InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: File not found : /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/process/src/test/resources/rcicsod_02.csv
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: UPD: test fails when running in Jenkins only, when running locally there is no issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the **absolute path**.

```
String path =new File("src/test/resources/rcicsod_02.csv").getAbsolutePath();
File file = detector.getLocalFile(path);
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me the core difference between my code and your solution? Also, test fails when running in Jenkins only, when running locally there is no issues.